# get_absolute_url - Django`s sitemap

Tags: python, django

I want to enable sitemap-generation in Django, so I do the following, how it explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#example)

model:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=10)
    active = models.BooleanField()
```

urls:

```
car_dict = {
    'queryset': Car.objects.filter(active=1),
}

sitemaps = {
    #'flatpages': FlatPageSitemap,
    'car': GenericSitemap(car_dict, priority=0.5),
}
```

But I have an error on /sitemap.xml: **'Car' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url**. How to fix it? I need to create some classes, how it explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#a-simple-example)? Or I can use only GenericSitemap? I commented 'flatpages', because I dont use them. Thanks.

Update 1:
in URLS.py:

```
url(r'^car/$', 'cars.views.shop'),
    url(r'^car/(?P<car_id>\d+)/$', 'cars.views.producer'),
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to define [get_absolute_url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) for the model:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=10)
    active = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('car_details', kwargs={'name':self.name})
```

Please update the URL reverse method according to the URL you have defined.

Comment: 'car_details' - its a part of url (site.com/car_details) ?

Comment: No `car_details` is the url name. Can you please post `urls.py` so that i can help you more, i need the url for the Car model how you have defined it in your urls.py?

Comment: oh, thanks, I read [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#get-absolute-url) and your code helps me) but I use return "/car/%i/" % self.id and its work. Thanks.

Comment: I update my post, `return "/car/%i/" % self.id` returns car/1.. car/2.. but not returns car/

Comment: @tim this is the desired behaviour and it should be like that. The Site map will include all car urls.

Comment: but not car/ page. it includes car/1/, car/2/, but not include main page.

Comment: If you want `car/` you have to define it as `StaticSitemap` see [here](http://dpaste.com/856636/) and follow [this](http://tech.matchfwd.com/xml-sitemaps-in-django/) tutorial it has explained everything pretty well.

Comment: @AamirAdnan Please make your answer complete by adding proper imports to address issues like `global name 'reverse' is not defined`

Comment: Had the same issue, answer is for python 3 - for python 2.7 - def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('car_details', args=[str(self.name)]), working now :)